# How would you write an alternating row function using modulus in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've got an example here of a typical chunk of JavaScript (code that would apply a background style class to an alternating odd or even row in a table). I'm trying to rewrite this in CoffeeScript in my attempt to learn that. The CoffeeScript range syntax is different and more Ruby-esque. I'd really appreciate an example of how you would do this?

```
   function alternate(id){ 
     if(document.getElementsByTagName){  
       var table = document.getElementById(id);   
       var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");   
       for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){           
     //manipulate rows 
         if(i % 2 == 0){ 
           rows[i].className = "even"; 
         }else{ 
           rows[i].className = "odd"; 
         }       
       } 
     } 
    }
```

Update

I'm using JQuery and trying this but it doesn't work (it makes all rows #efefef):

```
$(document).ready ->
    rowCount = $('tbody tr')
    for row in rowCount        
        if row.length % 2 == 0
            $('tbody tr').css('background-color', '#363636')
        else
            $('tbody tr').css('background-color', '#efefef')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little more concise:

```
for row, i in $('tbody tr')
  color = if i % 2 is 0 then '#363636' else '#efefef'
  $(row).css 'background-color', color
```

Comment: That is so elegant! Can you break down and explain what is going on with this? I'm new to programming. The CoffeeScript docs are still too sparse for a beginner but if I get a good explanation I can understand

Comment: Sure. "for row, i in list" will run a loop for every item in the list, with the item assigned to the variable "row", and the current loop index number assigned to the variable "i". "$(tbody tr)" is our list of <tr> tags. The next line assigns either of the two CSS colors to the variable "color", depending on if "i" is even or odd. Finally, the third line uses jQuery's "css" function to set the "backround-color" CSS style.

Comment: This is great! I couldn't figure out how to get the index assigned to a variable I could use.

Comment: What if I want to have a column a red, two columns blue, a column red, two colums blue, and so on? Can you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 5):

You may also be interested in the even / odd meta selectors provided by jquery

```
$('tbody tr:even').css 'background-color', '#363636'
$('tbody tr:odd').css 'background-color', '#efefef'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is just to apply a different style to odd/even rows, you can try this:

```
// CSS file

#myTable tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #363636; }
#myTable tr:nth-child(odd)  { background-color: #efefef; }
```

No JS here, just plain CSS, which is good since styling is a presentation concern.

However it only works in (relatively) modern browsers: IE 9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Try `for row, i in rows`, where `i` holds the loop counter.